# Sharing model data between web applications

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web-applications, symfony1

I'm looking for the best possible way of sharing model data between two MVC (I'm using Symfony) driven web sites.

**Background information**

We have two web sites A and B. The same software is used for both sites, but there are different customers and data. Customers are allowed to release content. Now we're going to introduce a new payment option with the advantage that the user's content is released on both web sites automatically.

**Implementation ?!**

I have three ideas for the implementation:

1. Using the same database for both applications. Then I would have to extend some tables by one column which indicates the appropriate target web site (A/B).

   I think that this would be *bad design*. A lot of code has to be rewritten in order to exclude records from query result sets, which does not belong to the respective web site.
2. Using two databases.

   In my opinion, this would decrease performance significantly and would be very hard to implement. Data has always to be requested twice. Also, in future there may be web sites C,D,E...
3. Synchronizing two databases via web-service.

   Some data would be stored twice. Therefore, all operations on such a piece of data has to be performed twice (create, read, update, destroy).

Now I'm stuck, because each solution has serious disadvantages.

Do you have any ideas? If not, which one do you think is the best of mine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your first option is the best. You're going to reduce duplicate data as much as possible and you should have the best performance. You will have to add an extra check to exclude the records not belonging to each particular website but all solutions will require work.

Comment: Depending on how your model is set up, you may also be able to modify each site's FooPeer (Propel) or FooTable (Doctrine) classes to filter out the other site's data, without having to rewrite your individual queries.

Comment: I agree with @yitznewton - modify your model classes to apply the filter transparently and you've covered many instances. Remember to take into account your Join cases.

Comment: Do you think that the concept of multitenancy fits in this context? I could define each web-site as a tenant. If true, one maybe could use this symfony plugin: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfMultiTenantPlugin

Comment: Fishbone, yes, housing multiple customers (using common schema) in the same database is the very basis of multi-tenancy. sfMultiTenantPlugin should be a good solution to your query